# User is not constructor in Express with Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to implement registration in Express using passport.js and when I submit the form, on the server console I got:

```
POST /user/register 500 62.273 ms - 2008
TypeError: User is not a constructor
    at /mean-auth/server/routes/api.js:8:17
```

Here is the api.js file with error:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

var User = require('../models/user.js');

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  User.register(new User({ username: req.body.username }),
    req.body.password, function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        err: err
      });
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Registration successful!'
      });
    });
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

User model (`user.js`) looks like:

```
// user model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
  User: User
};

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

and I also tried with `createUser` method and `newUser` object:

```
var User = require('../models/user.js');

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  var newUser = new User({
    username: username,
    password: password
  });

  User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(user);
  });

  passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: 'Registration successful!'
    });
  });
});
```

but the same error appears. 
Is there something wrong with the definition of the User?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are exporting an object with the User inside it.

```
module.exports = {
  User: User
};
```

When importing that file, try to do it like this:

```
var User = require('../models/user.js').User;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.js` extension in the require statement.

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```